# convert vector<string> into char** C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a `vector<std::string>` variable. I need to pass it onto a method which accepts `char**`as an input parameter.

how to do this ? If possible I need to pass a writable one.

**Update 1:**
In a tool for creating a service method, i give parameters as std::vector, but it sets automatically the qualifier as &, which means my method definition generated by the tool will look as:

```
std::string SvcImpl::myMethodname ( const std::string par1, const std::vector<     std::string >& par2, const std::vector< std::string >& par3 )
{

}
```

This method gets called automatically with values in the patameter passed.
Now from inside this method I'm going to call a method in a dll in a lib folder which looks like:

```
int method_to_be_called(char* par1, char ** par2, char ** par3, void* pRetValue);
```

for par1 --> I'm passing (char*)par1.c_str()

I need to know how to pass variables for par2 and par3 and for pRetValue.
values for par2 and par3 are available in vector but the last parameter pRetValue is an output parameter that i need to return it as std::string.

sorry if i am very confusing or asking very basic questions.

Comment: then your operation should be on `*writable`, assuming **writable is accepting your char ** param.

Comment: I think you are going to need to produce a new `std::vector<char*>` to store the addresses of all your string data.

Comment: What exactly does this method you are passing it to do?

Comment: Do you really need to copy the contents of the strings into a newed array, or can you just use a pointer to the underlying data directly?

Comment: @juanchopanza The "underlying data" would be an array of string objects, you can't just iterate through them as if they were an array of c-strings.

Comment: @Wlerin I meant the underlying data of each string.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the function is meant to operate on an array of c-strings (hence the char** parameter). He could try passing them individually, I guess. It depends what this function actually does with them.

Comment: @Wlerin Sigh. If OP can just use the underlying data of each string, there is no need to copy it into a newed array, so all you need is an array containing pointers to the underlying data of each string. As in Galik's answer.

Comment: Your function signature does not accept the array lengths. Does this mean the function deduces the array lengths from a null terminator? Or are they fixed? This effects the answer.

Comment: @Galik you are right. It needs array lenghts.. I need to add parameters for array lengths. I need to change the function to be called to accept array lengths as parameters now along with the respective arrays of strings.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is possible to solve the problem without copying out all the `std::strings` as long as the function **does not modify** the passed in `char**`. Otherwise I can see no alternative but to copy out everything into a new char**` structure ***(see second example)***.

```
void old_func(char** carray, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << carray[i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::vector<char*> cstrings;
    cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i)
        cstrings.push_back(const_cast<char*>(strings[i].c_str()));

    // Do not change any of the strings here as that will
    // invalidate the new data structure that relies on
    // the returned values from `c_str()`
    //
    // This is not an issue after C++11 as long as you don't
    // increase the length of a string (as that may cause reallocation)

    if(!cstrings.empty())
        old_func(&cstrings[0], cstrings.size());
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2:** If the function must modify the passed in data:

```
void old_func(char** carray, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << carray[i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    {
        // pre C++11
        std::vector<std::string> strings {"one", "two", "three"};

        // guarantee contiguous, null terminated strings
        std::vector<std::vector<char>> vstrings;

        // pointers to rhose strings
        std::vector<char*> cstrings;

        vstrings.reserve(strings.size());
        cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

        for(size_t i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i)
        {
            vstrings.emplace_back(strings[i].begin(), strings[i].end());
            vstrings.back().push_back('\0');
            cstrings.push_back(vstrings.back().data());
        }

        old_func(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size());
    }

    {
        // post C++11
        std::vector<std::string> strings {"one", "two", "three"};

        std::vector<char*> cstrings;   
        cstrings.reserve(strings.size());

        for(auto& s: strings)
            cstrings.push_back(&s[0]);

        old_func(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Revised to provide better code.

Comment: Good, although in the second version I would use a vector or at least a unique_ptr to hold the pointer array, and some kind of scope_exit facility to delete the pointers inside. If any of the individual string allocations fail here, all previous ones plus the pointer array are leaked.

Comment: in the comment of your code, you wrote that "this is not an issue after C++11." can you please explain why?

Comment: @lefenzy I edited the comment as it was not entirely accurate. But before `C++11` there is no guarantee that the pointer returned by `c_str()` points to the string's actual data (it may be a temporary buffer). After `C++11` it is guaranteed to point to the strings actual data. It is only invalidated if you *increase* the length of the string.

Comment: Been looking forever for a good answer -- this is what I needed that nobody else mentioned: the c_str() function!  Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Galik's answer has a number of safety issues. Here is how I would do it in Modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void old_func(char** carray, std::size_t size)
{
    for(std::size_t i(0); i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << carray[i] << '\n';
}

void other_old_func(const char** carray, std::size_t size)
{
    for(std::size_t i(0); i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << carray[i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "modifiable version\n";
        std::vector<std::string> strings{"one", "two", "three"};
        std::vector<char*> cstrings{};

        for(auto& string : strings)
            cstrings.push_back(&string.front());

        old_func(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size());

        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
    {
        std::cout << "non-modifiable version\n";
        std::vector<std::string> strings{"four", "five", "six"};
        std::vector<const char*> cstrings{};

        for(const auto& string : strings)
            cstrings.push_back(string.c_str());

        other_old_func(cstrings.data(), cstrings.size());
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

No messy memory management or nasty `const_cast`s.

[Live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a942c703c08c630)

Outputs:

```
modifiable version
one
two
three


non-modifiable version
four
five
six
```

Comment: Just be aware if you are using `&string.front` that the documentation states: "This function shall not be called on empty strings." I believe in practice it will be the same as `&string[0]` and `data` and `c_str` but it might trigger debug warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The top rated answers for this question expect you to pass in a size with your char** parameters. But in method_to_be_called() there is no way to pass in a size for par2 and par3 so these lists of c-style strings probably expect to be null terminated. In other words the last string (char*) in the list of strings (char **) needs to be a null pointer.  This is a common paradigm in many c libraries.

```
int method_to_be_called(char* par1, char ** par2, char ** par3, void* pRetValue);
```

The most expedient way around this is probably to go with a more c-style answer.

```
//directly create char** par2
std::vector<std::string> par2Vect{"one", "two", "three"};
char ** par2 = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*)*(par2Vect.size() + 1) );
for(size_t i = 0; i < par2Vect.size(); ++i)
{
    par2[i] = strdup(par2Vect[i].c_str());
}
// set the last entry to null to signify the end of the list
par2[par2Vect.size()] = nullptr;

// call your library
method_to_be_called(..., par2,...);

// delete par2
for(size_t i = 0; i < par2Vect.size(); ++i)
{
    // free memory for each c-style string
    free(par2[i]);
}
// free memory for outer char* array 
free(par2);
```

Comment: memory allocated with `strdup` uses `malloc` and thus should be freed using `free` not `delete`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is rather easy and can be done without too much of complexity.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vector = {"a", "std::vector", "of", "std::string"};
// Result char**.
char** result = new char*[vector.size()];
for (int index = 0; index < vector.size(); index++) {
    result[index] = const_cast<char*>(vector[index].c_str());
}
// Use the result.
delete[] result;
// Deallocate the memory from heap after usage.
```

Comment: This is ultimately identical to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032303/1889329), except with manual memory management. This doesn't add anything useful.